# Clean URLs on nginx responding with 404 after SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, nginx

I added SSL to my site and am able to access the other pages fine when hosting locally, but it does not work anymore when it's hosted online.

For example, I can access http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:3000/test. I can also access https://example.com, but I can't access https://example.com/test or https://example.com/other.

I'm using node and express for the back end along with nginx. I think it has something to do with my virtual host, but this is all I have so far.

```
server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /home/anon/cert_chain.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/anon/example.com.key;

  root /srv/www/example.com/public_html;
  index index.html;

  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;

  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

access log:

```
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:48:39 -0500] "GET /stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 366 "https://example.com/api" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:48:40 -0500] "GET /service-worker.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://example.com/service-worker.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:55 -0500] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 366 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:55 -0500] "GET /stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 366 "https://example.com/api" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:55 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 4286 "https://example.com/api" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:56 -0500] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 366 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:56 -0500] "GET /stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 366 "https://example.com/api" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:56 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 4286 "https://example.com/api" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:56 -0500] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 404 366 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:56 -0500] "GET /stylesheets/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 366 "https://example.com/api" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
153.6.67.184 - - [23/Jan/2016:06:49:56 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 4286 "https://example.com/api" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
```

error log:

```
2016/01/22 20:00:09 [notice] 8121#0: signal process started
2016/01/22 20:09:22 [notice] 8442#0: signal process started
2016/01/22 20:09:57 [notice] 8468#0: signal process started
2016/01/22 20:11:47 [notice] 8544#0: signal process started
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant lines from your `nginx` access and error logs?

Comment: @RichardSmith I have added them in, although the error log doesn't have anything substantial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that I didn't have MongoDB running on the server and that was the whole reason it didn't load the API. nginx was working fine all along.